# OpenCV2.4 python - Stereo Matching and Disparity map

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, matching, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

Hy!

I would like to get a disparity map and a stereo matching from to stereo images with python2.7 and opencv2.4.

I have been googling but i didn't find any understandable python code, like this one:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

do you have any good advise??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok that was easy!

i just checked on my folder: C:\opencv\samples\python2

there you can find a lot and good samples like stereo_match.py